# validate method call on Create only, not for on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, ruby-on-rails-2, jrubyonrails

I have validate method in my model

```
def validate
  super    
  if some condition
    errors.add('', 'some text')
  end
end
```

This method call on Create and Update. I don't want to call on Update. How can I do that?

I am using rails2.3.11 and jruby.

Update:
I can use this one `validate :custom_validation, :on => :create`, but How they called on Create and Update??

I also checked `validate_on_create`, but still I am not figureout when this `validate` called?

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
validate :custom_validation, :on => :create
```

and change your method name from `validate` to `custom_validation` i.e.

```
def custom_validation
  super    
  if some condition
    errors.add('', 'some text')
  end
end
```

and the above method will call only on create and not on update

Answer (score 0):

Using `:on => :create`, for me had unexpected results in an older application running Rails 4.2.5.1

I would not expect my below validation to be called when I called `.valid?` but it was being called.

```
a) My Test Model contained `validate :exec_on_create, :on => :create`.
b) In console
001 > t = Test.new(msg: '7 ...')
002 > t.valid?
******* "exec_on_create" was called.
=> true
```

Changing `:on => :create`  to  `before_create :exec_on_create`, performed more to what I would expect ... no longer called the validation that was supposed to be called only on create.

```
a) My test Model contained `before_create :exec_on_create`.
b) In console
001 > t = Cals2Db::Test.new(msg: '7 ...')
002 > t.valid?
=> true
```